# ServiceStack, requests, thread id's, log4net

Tags: asp.net, log4net, servicestack

I have the need to have an option to enabled deep debug logging using log4net.  I am familiar with how classic ASP.Net handles threads, but I wondered how threads work with ServiceStack.  The goal would be to use %Thread to group requests together in the log.  I think the only problem is that there is likely a thread pool and the %thread id will be reused on subsequent requests.

Really what I am looking for is a single unique id I can expose to log4net so I can group the entire logging of a single request together when building a report.

Can anyone lend some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this page on [concurrency in ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Concurrency-model), i.e. ServiceStack when hosted in ASP.NET doesn't create any new threads itself, requests are simply handled on the same IIS/Nginx/etc ASP.NET HTTP WebWorker that handles the request. Ultimately control of the Thread Pool and thread instances is up to the underlying ASP.NET but its common for them to re-use the same threads to handle different requests.

Use `IHttpRequest.Items` whenever you want to **share any data** throughout the lifetime of a single request, e.g. you could simply assign a Guid at the [start of the request](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) using a PreRequestFilters with:

```
this.PreRequestFilters.Add((req, res) => req.Items["ReqId"] => Guid.NewGuid());
```

Which lasts the entire lifetime of the request and the same instance of `IHttpRequest` is available in all filters, services, views, etc.